# Android sharing intent won't work with reddit

Tags: java, android

My sharing intent code does work with all other apps but not reddit when i try to share it with reddit i get a toast saying "Something went wrong." I tried several codes but none worked for me. Here's my current code, Please help me solving this problem.

```
 private void share(File file){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///"+file.getAbsolutePath()));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share with..."));
    }
```

Comment: Does reddit show up as an option to share to? If it does, are you saying that the error happens when you click on reddit as an option?

Comment: yeah reddit gets shown there and when i click on it the toast appears. @Dylan